# Extending V8 JavaScript engine

Tags: javascript, binding, v8

http://docs.python.org/2/extending/
I have some experience with extending/embedding the python interpreter. I also know some of the tools that make this easier like cython.

Now I am curious about doing the same with Google's V8 engine. I am more interested about extending it but didn't find much information about doing this.

Can anyone recommend further reading? Do tools exist that make this easier?

Answer (score 0):

## Re. Further Reading:

[NodeJS Documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/addons.html)

[Kenneth Geisshirt's 2015 Talk](https://realm.io/news/oredev-kenneth-geisshirt-extending-node-js-cpp/) (crash course)

## Re. Tools:

**Short Answer**: no.

**Long Answer:** Since one language is being compiled by the other, debuggers will intrinsically have a hard time crossing the language barrier. Instead, I strongly recommend you perform exhaustive unit testing, especially when you consider that JavaScript is loosely typed and C++ is strongly typed. That difference alone may cause or save headaches when developing extensions.